# How to un-ubuntu a flashdrive

Tags: system-installation

I recently fixed my friends computer, and installed Ubuntu 13.10 on to it.
To do this, I used my flash-drive (he had no disc reader). However, now I want to undo what I did to the flash drive.

I created the drive on Mac OSX following the official websites instructions to create the flash drive. I have already formatted the drive in windows, but now it's only 2.7 MB big.

How can I un-Ubuntu the drive? I'd really like to not have to buy a new one.

EDIT: Instructions on how to do this on EITHER OS (Mac or Windows) are good. I don't have access to the Ubuntu machine any longer. (sadface again)

Comment: How did you install Ubuntu on it? And how did you format it in Windows? Also, read the [help] to learn *why* you aren't allowed to add "Hello". We aren't a forum ;)

Comment: I followed the instructions on the official website for creating a bootable USB. I then installed Ubuntu 13.10 off of the drive (by selecting it from boot-priorities in the BIOS) and ran the install like normal. I then plugged the drive into my Windows machine (I used my mac to create the drive because I was away from my Windows machine when I created it). I right clicked the drive in the list of devices, hit "Format..." and selected a format of FAT32.

Comment: @Seth Thank you for making the use of the word "Hello" on the site clear to me. I guess that's useful to know!

Comment: What was the size of the driver *before* you reformatted it?

Comment: Anywhere from 4-8 gigabytes, I believe. Not very sure about this. I've just had it lying around for doing exactly this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Windows:

```
Control Panel -> Administrative Tools -> Computer Management -> Disk Management
```

Delete all the partitions on your flashdrive one-by-one by right-clicking on each partition and selecting `Delete Volume`. Then create a single partition on the free space and format it as NTFS or FAT32.

Comment: Thank you for the reply! I had my Mac in front of me, so I used basically the same process to undo what I have done on from my Mac. Appears to be working thus far. If all succeeds, I will for-sure give you that all important green check. Thank you so much!

Comment: Working perfectly! Thank you so much for your help!